# Como funciona ciclo de vida Injeção de dependência?

Tags: java, c#, asp.net-mvc, injeção-de-dependência

Como funciona o 3 ciclos de vida de uma injeção de dependência tais como 
singleton, transient e scope ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singleton : Um objeto do serviço é criado e fornecido para todas as requisições. Assim, todas as requisições obtém o mesmo objeto;

Transient : sempre gerará uma nova instância para cada item encontrado que possua tal dependência, ou seja, se houver 5 dependências serão 5 instâncias diferentes

scoped : essa diferente da Transient que garante que em uma requisição seja criada um instância de um classe onde se houver outras dependências, seja utilizada essa única instância pra todas, renovando somente nas requisições subsequentes, mas, mantendo essa obrigatoriedade.

Comment: Eduardo afinal qual a diferença entre scoped e transient? pelo que entendi o objeto do serviço é criado para cada requisição?

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro achei uma definição melhor ve se ficou claro

Comment: Agora sim! +1! Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!